# Sort labels of segmented image in kmeans based on cluster mean

Tags: algorithm, matlab, image-processing

I have a simple question but is very interesting. As you know, Kmeans can be give different result after each running due to randomly initial cluster center. However, assume I know that cluster 1 has smaller mean value than cluster 2, cluster 2 has smaller mean value than cluster 3 and so on. I want to make a algorithm to implement that cluster has small mean value, then it will be assigned to small cluster index.

This is my Matlab code. If you are have more sort or more clear way. Please suggest to me

```
 %% K-mean
 num_cluster=2;
 nrows = size(Img_original,1);
 ncols = size(Img_original,2);
 I_1D = reshape(Img_original,nrows*ncols,1);
 [cluster_idx    mu]=kmeans(double(I_1D),num_cluster,'distance','sqEuclidean','Replicates',3);
 cluster_label = reshape(cluster_idx,nrows,ncols);
 %% Sort based on mu
 [mu_sort id_sort]=sort(mu);
 idx=cell(1,num_cluster)
 %% Save index of order if mu
 for i=1:num_cluster
    idx{i}=find(cluster_label==id_sort(i));
 end
 %% Sort cluster label based on mu
 for i=1:num_cluster
    cluster_label(idx{i})=i;
 end
```

Comment: I don't understand. First, what is the "mean value" of a cluster ? As k-means generally works in multidimensional spaces it seems ill-defined to me. Then, what is your question ?

Comment: mean value that means the average value of that cluster. In mathematics, It denotes by mu. My question is how to make the output of kmeans subject to the small cluster_label is for cluster with small mean value

Comment: OK, you're talking of the centroid of the cluster, not of the (ill-defined) "mean value". As your initial vectors are in 2D, it is not possible to compare them like "x is greater than y" and so you can't compare them with `sort`. I think there is no hope in what you're trying to do.

Comment: No no. I think you were misunderstand my problem. I assume that centroid of the clusters are approximated before. That means that I know cluster 1 has smaller centroid than cluster 2. For example, I have a 2D image and it has Background and Foreground. I know that intensity of Foreground is brightness region then it has centroid bigger than Background that has black region. I want to use kmeans and the output of kmean must be assign label 1 for Background and 2 for foreground. That is my work

Comment: Then you can look at my code. After use kmean, we has cluster center and labels. Then I sort cluster center and assign label for each cluster based on mean sorting

Comment: I'm sorry, your English is too poor for me, I give up trying to understand what you write. Good luck anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear to me as to why you'd want to relabel the clusters based on the ordering of each centroid.  You can simply use the labelling vector that is output from k-means to reference which cluster / centroid each point belongs to.

Nevertheless, the initial idea that you had to sort the centroids is a good one.  The last part of your code seems rather inefficient because you're looping over each label and doing the reassignment.  One thing I could perhaps suggest is to have a lookup table where the input is the original label and the output is the reordered labels based on the sorted centroids.

If you want to pursue this route, you can use a [`containers.Map`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/map-containers.html) where the keys are the labels given from the sort order that is output from `sort`, and the values are the reordered labels... namely, a vector that goes from 1 up to as many classes you have.  You need to do this because the second output of `sort` tells you where each value in the original array would appear in the sorted result, so you must use this ordering to properly perform the relabelling.  In addition, I would use the [`sortrows`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sortrows.html) function in MATLAB, not raw `sort`.  With how you're doing it, you are sorting each **column / variable** independently and that will give the wrong centroids.  This will work for grayscale images where you only have one feature to consider, namely the grayscale, but if you go beyond grayscale and perhaps go into RGB or whatever colour space you desire, using raw `sort` will give you incorrect results.  You need to consider each row as a single point, then sort the rows jointly.

Given your code, you'd do something like this:

```
%% K-mean
num_cluster=2;
nrows = size(Img_original,1);
ncols = size(Img_original,2);
I_1D = reshape(Img_original,nrows*ncols,1);
[cluster_idx    mu]=kmeans(double(I_1D),num_cluster,'distance','sqEuclidean','Replicates',3);

%% Sort based on mu
[mu_sort id_sort]=sortrows(mu);

%// New - Create lookup
lookup = containers.Map(id_sort, 1:size(mu_sort,1));

%// Relabel the vector
cluster_idx_sort = lookup.values(num2cell(cluster_idx));
cluster_idx_sort = [cluster_idx_sort{:}];

%// Reshape back to original image dimensions
cluster_label = reshape(cluster_idx_sort,nrows,ncols);
```

This should hopefully give you some speedup in your code.

---

To double check, I tried this on the `cameraman.tif` image, that's part of the image processing toolbox.  Running the code gives me these cluster centres:

```
>> mu

mu =

  153.3484
   23.7291
```

Once I sort the clusters in ascending order, this is what I get for the ordering and for the centroids:

```
>> mu_sort

mu_sort =

   23.7291
  153.3484

>> id_sort

id_sort =

     2
     1
```

So that works as we expected... now if we display the original cluster label map before sorting on the centroids with:

```
cluster_label = reshape(cluster_idx, nrows, ncols);
imshow(cluster_label,[]);
```

... we get this image:

[image]

Now, if we run through the sorting logic and display the centroids:

```
imshow(cluster_label, []);
```

... we get this image:

[image]

This works as I expected.  Because the centroids flipped, so should the colouring.

Comment: @rayeyeng: Thank you. But I run your above code and it give different result for each running test. Could you see it in my update question. I will delete it later

Comment: @user3051460 - I'll have a look.

Comment: @user3051460 - Ah, I flipped something.  Let me fix it.

Comment: @user3051460 - I fixed it.  I declared my `containers.Map` wrong.  Take a look at the line where `containers.Map(...)` is declared.  Flip the arguments and you'll get the right answer every time.

Comment: Oh, It corrects now. It is exactly what I need. +1 Vote

Comment: @user3051460 - Glad I could help!